# Why does EF Core not let me create a property without primary key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am quite new to EF Core and am trying to add a enum/string-value as a column in my `Order` table to be able to have a text status in my code like below and stores as a string in DB. But when I try to run the migration after I added the `OrderStatus` property I get this error:

> The entity type 'OrderStatus' requires a primary key to be defined.

I understand the error message, but how can you add a property on a EF Core entity that lets you just save the string in a column?

Calling code:

```
   var order = new Order();
   order.OrderStatus = OrderStatus.Ongoing;
```

Enum class:

```
public class OrderStatus : Enumeration
{
    public static readonly OrderStatus Ongoing 
        = new OrderStatus(0, "Ongoing");

    private OrderStatus() { }
    private OrderStatus(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) { }
}
```

Class:

```
public class Order : EntityBase
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating the singleton instance in the Enumeration class?

Comment: Order Status is a class, thats why EF Core treat it as an entity. However, you could use custom value converter to save either the id or the string to the db, requires EF Core 2.1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Comment: @Jobse: It's an pattern in domain driven design, to have `enum` like classes with can be enriched with behavior (logic)

Comment: @Tseng Still the Class Enumeration has an Id `value` in this case. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @Jobse: it's not public, the entity doesn't have a parameterless constructor (which is a requirement of EF Core), we don't know how the backing field is named (there are conventions if the property is read-only, otherwise it needs to be defined explicitly in the fluent config)

Comment: You need to define a key for entity, this key it's no the same PK in database, EF Core uses key for entity to save changes

Comment: I just found this article which seems to be what I’m looking for: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13485#issuecomment-426722772

Comment: OwnsOne() looks like a good solution, however I do not see anything allowing code in the owned object a la domain-driven design.  But you could probably use annotations to have EF ignore non-stored properties and all code is part of property getters/setters.

Comment: Just occurred to me that this raises a question that could be a full-on flame war ;D  Is it wise to create close dependencies between code and stored data?